how to get response from user in telegram bot php when trying to validate register & crypto payment
im trying to code a telegram bot for shop
in telegram bot user can select a product and pay the invoice and get product.
we have a section in bot for users who wants to be a reseller.
for registering as reseller user must do 4 jobs :
1 - create metamask wallet (validation : public address)
2 - create account in our site (validation : userID in site)
3 - buy product in site (validation : invoiceID)
4 - submit form in our site (validation : userID in site)
we have a button when user clicked we show user a new message with 4 inlineButtons.
when clicking on button 1 a new message sent to user with video and description for what user must do
under the message we have a button named : validate
i want when user click validate robot send new message and say something after that user send validation query and robot validate it.
i have write the code but stock on validator
after clicking the validate button , we sent a message and show user what we need for this step (for example wallet address) but i dont know how to see from bot what user sended
i think we must do something with previous message or something like callbackquery
but i dont know what to do...
can any one help me?
i use laravel and telegram-bot-sdk.com library

i have used a database for storing user states
first after user click start the process button we create a new record for this user(before that we check if the user has been joined to bot and chanel or not also if user completed the register in bot )
after that we process the steps and check user answers for the  values we want
for example :
if (preg_match('/^(0x)?[0-9a-fA-F]{40}$/' , $this->Data['message']['text'])){
    $WalletAddress = $this->Data['message']['text'];
    //get user wallet and store data ....
}

here when user send a wallet address to robot , you will receive the anser
and we will add a if/else and check for user state in DB if user has not passed step 1 we will get and check answer for first step and if user passed step 1 we will start step 2 works.....
for step 3,4 we can create regex because our site id's have a algorithme and  we can check if user passed user id or not.
for example :
 if (preg_match('/^id\d.alg$[0-9]]/i' , $this->Data['message']['text'])){

we can replace pattern to site our site pattern
and in the end if anyone has the better option and code style I will be happy to listen to your words
